# Using com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser as Jersey client serializer/deserializer?

Tags: java, jersey-client, jsonparser

Is it possible to use com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser as a serializer/deserializer for JSON data in Jersey client? and how if this is possible?

Comment: Please give us a detailed description of your issue with what you have tried to solve the issue.

Comment: The body for my requests and the responses are entities which extend com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson, the default Json Provider is not serializing the objects properly. I think com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory can. Can we override the default JSON provider to use com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory?

Answer (score 0):

I think Jersey does this automatically if you include the following. Here are the gradle package needs for this:

> compile
>   'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.28'
>
> compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.23.1'

To My understanding jersey will then use the jackson serializer/ deserializer